# UIElement() в NET.Core 3.1

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core

В библиотеке классов под NET.Core 3.1 возник конфликт с типом UIElement (не распознавал как тип). В документации сказано, что в Net.Core 3.1 в сборке "PresentationCore.dll" в пространстве имен "System.Windows" есть класс "UIElement".
Подскажите почему после подключения пространства имен "System.Windows" класс "UIElement" не распознан? Ну или можно ли в библиотеке классов под NET.Core 3.1 использовать Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref и через него ссылаться на PresentationCore? Заранее спасибо!

Скриншот из VS 2019:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю, речь идет о приложении на WPF? У вас возможно путаница с библиотеками, проект под  NET.Core, а библиотеки вы пытаетесь использовать из классического Net.Framework.

Comment: @Bulson Удалил все ссылки в сборке, кроме PresentationCore.dll. Получается проблема с PresentationCore.dll?

Comment: Новый же проект? Пересоздайте его как WPF приложение, возможно вы где-то поломали референсные ссылки на библиотеки или создали консольное приложение, а пытаетесь сделать из него WPF - не ясно. Покажите фрагмент кода, который не компилится. Я уже давно сижу на .NET Core 3.1 WPF и ни разу не встречал ничего подобного.

Comment: @aepot Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. После вашего совета пересоздал как wpf приложение - все заработало с добавлением System.Windows. Но меня интересует тип проекта "библиотека классов". Я изменил свой вопрос!

Comment: @PopMal тогда вам нужна либо WPF User Control Library либо WPF Custom Control Library. В вашем проекте не хватает зависимости фреймворка `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF`. Такая имеется в десктопном приложении, она и даст доступ к UI классам.

Comment: @aepot Огромное спасибо вам за ответы!